# how to make collision in flappybird?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

Ok, so I need to make a collision between the two pillars to the bird player. Sorry if the code is complicated, I am new to programming.

In the code, there are two pillars that move left and repeat.
I did xpos2, ypos2, xpos, ypos because there are 2 pillars at one moment.
The gap between them is 670 because the picture of the pillars is very big, 
so I drew them very high or low - you can't see all the pillar.
What I need to make a collision between each pillar (top or bottom) to the bird.
I tried with colliderect and another pygame func without success.

Thank you.

code

```py
import pygame
import random

size = [900, 504]
wait = pygame.time.Clock()
red = (255, 0, 0)
pygame.init()


class game:
    def __init__(self):
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((size[0], size[1])) 
        pygame.display.set_caption("Flappy Bird @yuv")
        self.background = pygame.image.load(r"d:\Users\Student\Desktop\background.png").convert()  
        self.top_pillar = pygame.image.load(r"d:\Users\Student\Desktop\top.png").convert()
        self.bottom_pillar = pygame.image.load(r"d:\Users\Student\Desktop\bottom.png").convert()
        self.done = False
        self.xpos = 400  # XPOS OF THE PILLARS
        self.xpos2 = 800 # 
        self.ypos_top = random.randint(-400, -200)  # ypos of the pillar - top
        self.ypos_bottom = self.ypos_top + 670  # ypos of the pillar - bottom
        self.ypos2_top = random.randint(-400, -200)  # ypos of the pillar - bottom
        self.ypos2_bottom = self.ypos2_top + 670  # ypos of the pillar - bottom
        self.score = 0

    def pillars(self):
        for i in range(5):
            self.xpos -= 1
            self.xpos2 -= 1
        if self.xpos <= 0:
            self.xpos = 800
            self.ypos_top = random.randint(-400, -200)  # ypos of the pillar - top
            self.ypos_bottom = self.ypos_top + 670  # ypos of the pillar - bottom
        if self.xpos2 <= 0:
            self.xpos2 = 800
            self.ypos2_top = random.randint(-400, -200)  # ypos of the pillar - bottom
            self.ypos2_bottom = self.ypos2_top + 670  # ypos of the pillar - bottom

   # def collide(self):
            ## how the hell i do it ! ? ?! ?! ?! ?!

    def scoregame(self):
        if bird().x > self.xpos or bird().x > self.xpos2:  
            self.score += 1
        myfont = pygame.font.SysFont('Comic Sans MS', 30)
        textsurface = myfont.render('score : ' + str(int(self.score / 39)), True, red)
        self.screen.blit(textsurface, (0, 0))

    def gameover(self):
        font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 55)
        text = font.render("Game Over!", False, red)
        self.screen.blit(text, [100, 250])
        self.done = True  


class bird:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 200
        self.y = 350
        self.bird = pygame.image.load(r"d:\Users\Student\Desktop\player.png").convert_alpha()

    def move_bird(self):
        wait.tick(20)
        for i in range(3):
            self.y += 2
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                    for i in range(50):
                        self.y -= 1

    def check_obstacle(self):
        if self.y > 478 or self.y < -10:  # check if the player touch the top or the bottom of the screen
            print('3')
            Game.gameover()


Game = game()
birdfunc = bird()
while Game.done == False:
    Game.screen.blit(Game.background, (0, 0))
    Game.screen.blit(birdfunc.bird, (birdfunc.x, birdfunc.y))
    birdfunc.move_bird()
    birdfunc.check_obstacle()
    Game.screen.blit(Game.top_pillar, (
    Game.xpos, Game.ypos_bottom))  # ypos -500 is the start of the top between -400 to -200 XXXXX gap- 200

    Game.screen.blit(Game.bottom_pillar, (Game.xpos, Game.ypos_top))  # ypos 500 is the start of the bottom

    Game.screen.blit(Game.top_pillar, (Game.xpos2, Game.ypos2_bottom))  # ypos -500 is the start of the top between -400 to -200 XXXXX gap- 200

    Game.screen.blit(Game.bottom_pillar, (Game.xpos2, Game.ypos2_top))  # ypos 500 is the start of the bottom
    Game.scoregame()
    Game.pillars()
    pygame.display.flip()
while Game.done == True:
    Game.screen.blit(Game.background, (0, 0))
    Game.gameover()
```

Comment: Please *post* (as opposed to linking to) the *minimal* code relevant to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You're already pretty close... I see that you've got code for collisions with the top and bottom of the screen already written. You don't need a library to do simple collision handling between objects either, in this case you can probably write your own algorithm.

```py
def check_obstacle(self):
    if self.y > 478 or self.y < -10:  # check if the player touch the top or the bottom of the screen
        print('3')
        Game.gameover()
```

How might you modify this to make the bird collide with pillars?

Here's my initial thought: The pillar edges could be simplified to different values of `self.y`, so if the bird is outside the range of valid y values in-between the pillars when the pillar goes by (do you have a `pillar.x`?), it should call `Game.gameover()`. Drawing a picture and labeling it with coordinates on paper might help you work out the math.